# How do I solve the difference in image quality that occurs only on Android in flutter?

Tags: flutter

my app was built on flutter.
The image quality of the IOS and Android versions are different for the same version and use the same code.
IOS on the left and Android on the right. There is a clear difference in resolution.

[image]

It receives stream from firestore and brings up images.
I can't solve this problem. It's going to be released next week, and it's a big problem. I'd appreciate it if anyone could help.

```
      StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('prod').document(widget.document.documentID).snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot2) {
            if(snapshot2.hasData){
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
            }
            return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                
                  Image.network(snapshot2.data['detail_img'], fit: BoxFit.cover),
               
              ]
            );
          }
        ),
```

Comment: on right side, is it emulator or real device?

Comment: this is real device. i connected with Mac and see it on screen. The IOS device is also real device, it comes in good quality.

Comment: ok. what looks like is pixelation. I think you image is too big and being scaled down. Try to give some cachedHeight and cachedWidgth to your Image.network widget. It should work fine then.

Answer (score 0):

I has the same problem in image.network on flutter web. On mobile, i just set `filterQuality: FilterQuality.medium` for solved